# How to prevent Eclipse changing backslashes to slashes?

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

Working on a Eclipse (C++, makefile) project and often Eclipse thinks to help me when changing \ to / for #include directives. Since we're using a "shared code base" (using unit-tests with MS-Test in C++) it is annoying when Eclipse changes \ to / for #include directives automatically and so getting a mix of \ and / ...

How to disable this "feature"?

When I type #include

```
#include <Communication\Types\BlaBla.h>
```

not:

```
#include <Communication/Types/BlaBla.h>
```

Comment: Since Windows XP, POSIX compliance is included: `/` is a valid file separator.

Comment: You should always use `/` in order to keep the code portable (to Unix-like systems for instance)

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but: No.
1. Will not replace tons of existing #includes only because Eclipse is forcing me doing what I am not willed to do. Visual Studio does it better ;-)
2. Code will never run on Unix-like systems (Btw, Microsoft is so nice that Visual Studio works with \ AND / ... but Unix-like systems are thinking they're the one and only and like to force everyone doing what they want?

Yes it WORKS (COMPILES) but I want to AVOID MIX and WE decided to use \ in Visual Studio and Eclipse but the Eclipse IDE must have a setting to turn this off??